# Solr query two fields is wrong

Tags: solr

Solr query two fields is wrong

[image: query=file_text_search_all:来了 debugQuery part1]

[image: query=file_text_search_all:来了 debugQuery part2]

[image: file_text_search_all:来了 AND dataType_s:filebank debugQuery part1]

[image: file_text_search_all:来了 AND dataType_s:filebank debugQuery part2]

[image: solr schema.xml]

[image: solr stopwrods.txt]

Comment: Please add information as content of your answer and not as images. Add the field types as well, and include debugQuery in your second example. Are you running in cloud mode? How many nodes? Are all nodes answering queries?

Comment: As MatsLindh suggested, it would be good if you include the output of the "debugQuery" in your question. In particular I would be interested in what "QParser" and "parsedquery" show.

Comment: It's running in cloud mode.It has three nodes.

Comment: Please don't use images to add content, as it makes it very hard to search for and to read properly. In your debugQuery above, the parsed string for your non-working query is the empty string. In your field definition you have a stopfilter before tokenization - I don't think that' supported (except for charfilters), so fix your field definition first. If the StopFilter contains terms that is the same as your input string, my guess is that it all gets removed.

Comment: Thank you very much,MatsLindh,you are right.It is really the StopFilter removed my terms . I changed the StopFilter,and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MatsLindh,you are right.It is really the StopFilter removed my terms . I changed the StopFilter,and succeeded.@MatsLindh